# IDA Pro does not recognize function

Tags: ida

I am reversing a program with IDA Pro, but for some reason it cannot recognize a function inside the text section.

Can someone show me how to reformat the codes (in the figure) as a function?

[image: Assembly]

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this error when function body contained some embedded data; it is normal for assembler code, but I never saw such technique with high level language, so code packers/obfuscators embed data pieces in code segment as anti-disassembling measure.

When unused random data appears in code, IDA can not detect function borders automatically.

So, in such obfuscated code, instead of `Create function` (or press `P`) at the function start you can use `Set function end` (or press `E`) at function end, and IDA will create function from last "non-function" code start to current function. From my experience, this way may work with `P` at the beginning of obfuscated function doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to go to encrypt_String and press P

Comment: and if it doesn't work you should see an error message in the Output window, probably with the understandable reason why.

Comment: .text:026AFB5C: The function has undefined instruction/data at the specified address.
Your request has been put in the autoanalysis queue. ??? i do not understand ? nothing happened later

Comment: @SieuTruc It looks like that IDA didn't recognize the data at this address (0x026AFB5C) as code . Save the database for backup and go to this address, and press <kbd>U</kbd> to undefine whatever it is there and then <kbd>C</kbd> , which will convert this data to code. After that press <kbd>P</kbd> on the start of the function again.